# Uploading APK file using Selenium

Tags: java, html, angularjs, selenium, automated-tests

I'm struggling with one problem in my test. I'm trying to upload an APK file, but when it comes to that step, nothing happens.

I've already tried simple sendKeys with path to the file and using AutoIT script, but both of them don't work.

Here is input:

```
<button uib-tooltip-html="uploadTooltip" ng-if="(privileges.update &amp;&amp; !uploadForm.$visible) || createNew" ng-click="this.value = null;" ng-file-select="uploadFile($files, uploadForm)" class="btn btn-xs btn-default ng-scope ng-isolate-scope" ng-disabled="status.disabled || progressPercentage" type="button" style="overflow: hidden;">
<i class="fa fa-fw fa-upload"></i>
        <input type="file" tabindex="-1" ng-file-generated-elem="true" style="width: 1px; height: 1px; opacity: 0; position: absolute; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; overflow: hidden;">
<input type="file" tabindex="-1" ng-file-generated-elem="true" style="width: 1px; height: 1px; opacity: 0; position: absolute; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; overflow: hidden;">
</button>
```

And what I tried(also using string with a full path for sendKeys):

```
String filePath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "src\\test\\APK\\com.airbnb.android.apk";
        tryToClearAndSendKeysForSeconds(5, UPLOAD_FILE_BUTTON, filePath); // method for sendKeys with wait, locator and string
```

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Users\\IdeaProjects\\Automated_Tests\\src\\test\\APK\\FileUpload.exe");
```

AutoIT:

```
ControlFocus(“Open”,””,”Edit1″)
ControlSetText(“Open”,””,”Edit1″,”D:\HDimage\profile.jpeg”)
ControlClick(“Open”,””,”Button1″)
```

I'm not sure if I am supposed to click upload button before sending a file when it comes to sendKeys, but when I do this (I'm using win 10 btw):
[image]

Will appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

Please follow steps to upload APK or any file:

a) Upload your file in tmp directory on server for temporary backup. like

```
String path = FILE_UPLOAD_COMMON_PATH + File.separatorChar + file.getName();

try(FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(path)){
    fileOutputStream.write(bs); // byte[] bs
}catch(Exception e) {
    throw e;
}
```

b) Now get from tmp directory and upload file using driver like,

```
String path = FILE_UPLOAD_COMMON_PATH + File.separatorChar + file.getName();
driver.findElements(By.id("files")).get(0).sendKeys(path);
```

May it will solve your problem.

Comment: Your answer didn't help sadly, but I figured out that problem was with RemoteWebDriver and I needed `LocalFileDetector`.